# Getting typeError:e is undefined in firebug while running a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with my code.I am getting data from post as an array and I am then displaying that data in box.

```
function worker() {
    var a = $("#BeeperBox");
    var delay =2000;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/index.php/admin/getLatest', 
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.upda,function(i, v){
                var out = v.name + v.mob ;
                $('span.blueName').html(out);
                $("#BeeperBox").show();
                timerId = setTimeout(function () {
                    a.hide();
                }, delay);
            });
        },
        complete: function() {
            // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
            setTimeout(worker, 50000);
        }
    });
}
```

When i run it firebug shows error: TypeError: e is undefined.

Comment: Have you followed the stack trace of the error ?

Comment: The quoting in the initialisation of `var a` is broken. Is it that way in the original code?

Comment: No it was not broken in my original code.

Comment: i think there is some other code that is breaking your script... post other function where youare using the `e`

Comment: It's showing that error in reference to "jquery-1.8.3.min.js" library.

Comment: It shows no error when i remove each function and just dump whole data as output.

Comment: Are you setting the proper headers for the AJAX response? You didn't specify a `dataType` option for `$.ajax`, so jQuery will attempt to parse the response based on the `Content-Type` header in the response. Are you setting it for JSON? Try using `console.log(typeof data);` to see what it's being parsed as

Comment: @Jai Why? I agree newest version is "best", but do you have a reason?

Comment: yeah I am encoding it as JSON on server side.

Comment: I think it has some bug fixes.....i think.

Comment: @user2257655 It doesn't matter if you encode it as JSON...jQuery doesn't know what you're sending back. Just set the `dataType` option as "json". Like `$.ajax({ url: '/index.php/admin/getLatest', dataType: "json", success: func... });`

Comment: @Ian Thanks man, I am not longer getting that error.Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since your sending the response as JSON.. its better to specify your `dataType` as JSON (though  `If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response` ) so that you don't have to parse it manaully..i think the problem here is you havn't parsed the json that you got as response

try this

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/index.php/admin/getLatest', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data.upda,function(i, v){
      var out = v.name + v.mob ;
       ......
   },
```

Comment: and don't forget the header on php file :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if   data.upda is undefined, I think the problem is that that variable doesn't exist and you're trying to iterate over a undefined element.